# SQL case expression for date column to classify timestamps into a category

Tags: sql, timestamp, data-analysis, presto

Was trying to figure out a way in which I can use a case expression that gives me a col that classifies a date time into a meal time category like below,

```
  (CASE
      WHEN hour(order_time_local) < 6 THEN 'late night'
      WHEN hour(order_time_local) >=6 AND hour(order_time_local) < 11 THEN 'breakfast'
      WHEN hour(order_time_local) >=11 AND hour(order_time_local) < 14 THEN 'lunch'
      WHEN hour(order_time_local) >=14 AND hour(order_time_local) < 17 THEN 'mid-day'
      WHEN hour(order_time_local) >=17 AND hour(order_time_local) < 22 THEN  'dinner'
ELSE 'late night'
    END) as mealtime
```

but I used that for a column that just had the time, how would I use that if the column also had the day in it? Like below

```
    CREATED_DATE
2018-05-18 18:12:16.289
2018-03-29 17:05:46.489
2019-03-28 16:05:19.858
```

Comment: AFIAK, `hour` could also take a timestamp argument, couldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be you can cast the timestamp as date and use it within `hour` function

```
hour(cast(CREATED_DATE as date))
```

The following link will give you some further idea.

https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: You should be able to do without the `cast`. In fact, OP's code should work without any modification.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL server then please try this.

```
 (CASE
      WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) < 6 THEN 'late night'
      WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) >=6 AND  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) < 11 THEN 'breakfast'
      WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) >=11 AND DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) < 14 THEN 'lunch'
      WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) >=14 AND DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) < 17 THEN 'mid-day'
      WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) >=17 AND DATEPART(HOUR,order_time_local) < 22 THEN  'dinner'
ELSE 'late night'                                   
    END) as mealtime
```

Comment: The question is tagged with Presto. There, the equivalent of `datepart` function is called `extract` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#extraction-function).